# Find from contact list, how many people install the same app like whatsapp in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, addressbook

Am developing one app where user has to register with his/her mobile number and am storing that number on my server.So i want to find how many people from his/her contacts list has installed that same app. Using `AddressBook.framework` am able to get all contacts but i am get confused how to process the contacts list with my server. Please guide me the process.

Comment: Please be aware that ask a phonenumber to have you app function may cause a rejection by the review team: **17.2** `Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected`

Comment: But how whatsapp and viber apps process with contact numbers.

Comment: Luck I guess, the review baord is not known for there constancy. I have app reject that required the user phone number.

Comment: Let forget about rejection of app. Now any way to process my contactlist with my server.

Comment: Well you just create a webservice to which you can send all the phonenumbers and then match the phonenumbers with the one's you have of your registered users.

Comment: Don't do it unless you ask the users permission to do it.

Comment: Also I strongly suggest you use hashed numbers to increase security and likelyness of being accepted.